# Draw border of QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

How to draw border of `QGraphicsItem` ? Simple `painter->drawRect( boundingRect() )` in overloaded paint method is not correct(bottom-right corner is outside the item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem. Thanks for all advises, but now I see, that my problem was elsewhere.

I can draw a `QRectF()`, which fits to boundingRect of my item, but... when I scale my `QGraphicsView` (no matter if I use `fitInView()` method, or my own implementation) there are some errors in displaying my border.

Rarely one or two lines of rect are tighter then others. I think that it can be be related to my `QGraphicsItem`s, which are also `QGraphicsSvgItem`s at once.

Answer (score 4):

The coordinate system for graphics and drawing shapes can be tricky to get straight. You will often find yourself programming test drawings to get it right but it is drawing precisely what you are telling it to draw. You need to understand the [coordinate system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/coordsys.html). On this page, pay particular attention to the picture of "One pixel wide pen" for `QRectF`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the docs for [QPainter::drawRect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawRect) mention the actual width:

> A filled rectangle has a size of rectangle.size(). A stroked rectangle has a size of rectangle.size() plus the pen width.

Given that, I'd imagine you'd want something slightly more complicated than just using the bounding rectangle:

```
QRect r = boundingRect();
QPen p = painter->pen();
painter->drawRect(QRect(r.x(), r.y(), r.width()-p.width(), r.height()-p.width()));
```

Answer (score 2):

[QGraphicsEffect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html) may be your friend here. You can subclass it to draw a border around an arbitrary QGraphicsItem. Just remember to reimplement `boundingRectFor()` to include the extra border.